# Rails migration generation with options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, command, migration, tablecolumn

In Rails we have command to add migration that specifies the table name column name.
For example :

```
$ rails generate migration AddPartNumberToProducts part_number:string
```

will generate

```
class AddPartNumberToProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :products, :part_number, :string
  end
end
```

I know we can add the options on migration file, below migration will add part_number column after description column on products table.

```
class AddPartNumberToProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :products, :part_number, :string, :after => :descritpion 
  end
end
```

**Problem:  How to specify the options (example :after => :descritpion) on command line so that it will add directly on migration file.**

Any ideas.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: to my knowledge there even no way to pass default.

Comment: what do you mean specifying options ?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify column modifiers in a "hash-like" format after the column. Unfortunately, `after` is not one of the [supported modifiers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#column-modifiers).